# Is there a better way to write this incredibly long regex, or perform this error check?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I was trying to find a way to error/style correct a non-standard custom menu file from a decade old video game that I was working on in Notepad++ and this was the best I could come up with.

The below returns any curly brackets that aren't followed by an EOL character **or** are preceded by anything other than line start and 1-4 tabs, it works fine but seems like it could be a lot more elegant. **Any returned brackets are incorrect** unless they're the first or last in the file. More tabs are technically okay highly unlikely.

```
    (?<!^\t)(?<!^\t\t)(?<!^\t\t\t)(?<!^\t\t\t\t)[{}]|[{}](?!\R)
```

Properly formatted:

```
    Menu "MenuName"
    {
        Menu "SubMenuName"
        {
            Option "OptionName" "Command"
            Option "OptionName" "Command"
        }
    }
// This is a comment line
// [ curly brackets in comment lines are made square so they don't get counted as balancing
```

All curly brackets should be on a separate line by themselves with nothing but preceding tabs. They should also be paired but I've got a plugin handling that.

Improperly formatted:

```
    Menu "MenuName"{
        Menu "SubMenuName"
        {
            Option "OptionName" "Command"
            Option "OptionName" "Command"   }
    }Menu "That bracket would be wrong since the line should end afterwards.
    {   //this would also be wrong
// Nothing should ever follow a bracket except a End Of Line character.
```

Is there some better way to implement this search/check, considering Notepad++ uses Boost regex and doesn't allow variable-length lookbehinds? Also perhaps keeping in mind that I learned everything I know about regex last night.

The expression also returns the first (no preceding tab) and last (no EOL character) but I'm okay with that particular behavior.

---

The full content of a file I use as a template:

It loads from a loose file in the data folder, completely as is.

```
//DO NOT DELETE, needs a line here for some reason.
Menu "MenuNameTEMPLATE"
{
    Title "TitleName"
    Option "OptionName" "Command"
    Divider
    LockedOption
    {
        DisplayName "OptionName"
        Command "Command"
        Icon "IconName"
        PowerReady "PowerIdentifiers"
    }
    LockedOption
    {
        DisplayName "OptionName"
        Command "Command"
        Icon "IconName"
        Badge "BadgeIdentifiers"
    }
    LockedOption
    {
        DisplayName "OptionName"
        Command "Command"
        Icon "IconName"
    }
    Menu "SubMenuName"
    {
        Title "TitleName"
        Option "OptionName" "Command"
        Option "OptionName" "Command"
    }
}
```

Comment: Show some examples of what should be accepted and what should be rejected.

Comment: Good point, I added an example of what it should look like. Any duplicates would also be a problem but the lookahead would catch that.

Comment: Sigh. I tried to add [tag:regex-perl] or [tag:perl-regex] but it seems impossible. [tag:perl-regex] exists, but doesn't stick (and has zero questions tagged) so I guess it's a tag alias for [tag:regex].

Comment: @sehe what about pcre?

Comment: @SecretCisco seems more confusing than anything because that is its own library, but I guess... Better than nothing. (I was wondering where [_"Stackoverflow prompted tagging the regex flavor"_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71529024/is-there-a-better-way-to-write-this-incredibly-long-regex-or-perform-this-error?noredirect=1#comment126436365_71535036) since that might warrant a question on [Meta] since it doesn't seem at all possible.

Comment: @Sehe if you tag a question just "regex" when you hit "Review your question" it'll ask you to "Include a tag for one specific engine or language (perl, pcre, c#, etc)" I tagged it Boost because per the NP++ website: ["Notepad++ regular expressions use the Boost regular expression library..."](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/#regular-expressions) I have no opinion on the technical correctness of "flavor" as I only just learned literally any of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `^\h+[{}](?=\h*\R)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[{}]`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Find All in Current Document</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
  ^                   # beginning of line
    \h+                 # 1 or more horizontal spaces, you can use \t{1,4} if you only want tabulations
    [{}]                # open or close brace
    (?=                 # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
        \h*                 # 0 or more horizontal spaces
        \R                  # any kind of linebreak
    )                   # end lookahead
    (*SKIP)(*FAIL)      # skip this match and consider that fails
|                   # OR
    [{}]                # open or close brace
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: This is very cool and I'm definitely going to try to learn more about the (*SKIP)(*FAIL) part. It finds all the brackets with preceding errors with a lot less brute force but it doesn't find brackets with subsequent errors.

Comment: @SecretCisco: Sorry, I don't understand `it doesn't find brackets with subsequent errors`, what do you mean? Please, edit your question and add more test cases.

Comment: I edited it so it's hopefully more clear. But the line is supposed to end after the bracket, the only thing after it should be a line end, anything else is wrong.

Comment: @SecretCisco: Is this `^\h+[{}](?=\h*\R)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[{}]` OK for you? [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/g05V0X/1)

Comment: That's works perfectly, it handled everything I could think of throwing at it! I have no idea how it works but I think I can figure it out, thanks for helping! This does seem more elegant that throwing a stack of lookbehinds at the problem.

Comment: Oh, well it doesn't catch trailing tabs but that's and extremely minor thing that in no way impacts the actual execution of the file.

Comment: I actually figured it and and changed it to catch the extra tab(s) too! That regex101 site is real nice and a heck of a lot more convenient than color-coding an expression myself in GIMP.

Answer (score 1):

I want to start by saying that regex is 100% the wrong tool for this, you want a custom parser to handle both validating your file and parsing it into a model you can then use.

However, with the limitations imposed by your question, the following should do it:

```
^(?:[^{}]*|\t{1,4}[{}])$
```

Rather than worry about look-arounds, simply match what you expect to find. See it in action here: https://regex101.com/r/nYNqHw/1

Comment: I added some more information to the post, but I know a regex isn't optimal but I just need to check it for some errors. The game program handles the actual code on it's end, no parsing needed. That expression finds all brackets and everything in between them. I'm looking for just the out-of-place brackets, the ones that **don't** match what I'm expecting to find.

Comment: Same thing, you're focusing on what doesn't match, but an equivalent result is what matches. The lines that fail my regex are the ones you want to look at.

Comment: Okay, if I use it to mark rather than find it does in fact highlight everything that's correct. But the particular file I'm most concerned about is 3000+ lines long and lines with an error still get partially highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this Boost, and others rightfully remarked you need to not use regexes together with some editor facilities here, here's a starting point for a proper parser using Boost Spirit.

We'll parse into some types:

```
struct Option { std::string name, command; };
struct Divider { };

struct LockedOption {
    struct Property { std::string key, value; };
    using Properties = std::vector<Property>;
    Properties properties; // DisplayName, Command, Icon, PowerReady, Badge...?
};

struct Menu;
using MenuItem = boost::variant<Option, Divider, LockedOption,
                                boost::recursive_wrapper<Menu>>;
struct Menu {
    std::string                  id;
    boost::optional<std::string> title;
    std::vector<MenuItem>        items;
};
```

Now, we can define a parser:

```
namespace Parser {
    using namespace boost::spirit::x3;
    rule<struct menu_rule, Menu> const menu{"menu"};

    auto const qstring = rule<void, std::string>{"quoted string"} = //
        lexeme['"' > *('"' >> char_('"') | ~char_('"')) > '"'];

    auto const option = rule<void, Option>{"option"} = //
        "Option" > qstring > qstring;

    auto property   = (!lit('}')) > lexeme[+graph] > qstring;
    auto properties = rule<void, LockedOption::Properties>{"properties"} =
        *(property > eol);

    auto const lockedoption = rule<void, LockedOption>{"lockedoption"} = //
        "LockedOption" > eol                                             //
        > '{' > eol                                                      //
        > properties                                                     //
        > '}';

    auto divider = rule<void, Divider>{"divider"} = //
        lit("Divider") >> attr(Divider{});

    auto item = rule<void, MenuItem>{"menu|option|lockedoption|divider"} =
        menu | option | lockedoption | divider;

    auto title = "Title" > qstring;

    auto menu_def =            //
        "Menu" > qstring > eol //
        > '{' > eol            //
        > -(title > eol)       //
        > *(item > eol)        //
        > '}';

    auto ignore = blank | "//" >> *~char_("\r\n") >> (eol|eoi);

    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(menu)

    Menu parseMenu(std::string const& text) try {
        Menu result;
        parse(begin(text), end(text), skip(ignore)[expect[menu] > *eol > eoi],
              result);
        return result;
    } catch (expectation_failure<std::string::const_iterator> const& ef) {
        throw std::runtime_error(
            "At " + std::to_string(std::distance(begin(text), ef.where())) +
            ": Expected " + ef.which() + " (Got '" +
            std::string(ef.where(), std::find(ef.where(), end(text), '\n')) +
            "')");
    }
} // namespace Parser
```

All we need to use is the `parseMenu` function, which returns the parsed `Menu`. So if we wire up the samples from your question:

```
for (std::string const& sample :
     {
        // ... 
     })
{
    static int i = 0;
    fmt::print("----- {}\n", ++i);
    try {
        fmt::print("Parsed: {}\n", Parser::parseMenu(sample));
    } catch (std::exception const& e) {
        std::cout << "Parse failed: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

We can get the output (see live demo below):

```
----- 1
Parsed: Menu "MenuName"
{
    Title ""
    Menu "SubMenuName"
{
    Title ""
    Option "OptionName" "Command"
    Option "OptionName" "Command"
}
}
----- 2
Parse failed: At 19: Expected eol (Got '{')
----- 3
Parsed: Menu "MenuNameTEMPLATE"
{
    Title "TitleName"
    Option "OptionName" "Command"
    Divider
    LockedOption
{
    DisplayName "OptionName"
    Command "Command"
    Icon "IconName"
    PowerReady "PowerIdentifiers"
}
    LockedOption
{
    DisplayName "OptionName"
    Command "Command"
    Icon "IconName"
    Badge "BadgeIdentifiers"
}
    LockedOption
{
    DisplayName "OptionName"
    Command "Command"
    Icon "IconName"
}
    Menu "SubMenuName"
{
    Title "TitleName"
    Option "OptionName" "Command"
    Option "OptionName" "Command"
}
}
----- 4
Parse failed: At 70: Expected menu|option|lockedoption|divider (Got '                    Road Rage')
```

### LIVE DEMO

On Compiler Explorer: **https://godbolt.org/z/sW3Y5z9nq**

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_X3_DEBUG
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>

struct Option { std::string name, command; };
struct Divider { };

struct LockedOption {
#if 1
    struct Property { std::string key, value; };
    using Properties = std::vector<Property>;
#else
    using Properties = std::map<std::string, std::string>;
#endif
    Properties properties; // DisplayName, Command, Icon, PowerReady, Badge...?
};

struct Menu;
using MenuItem = boost::variant<Option, Divider, LockedOption,
                                boost::recursive_wrapper<Menu>>;
struct Menu {
    std::string                  id;
    boost::optional<std::string> title;
    std::vector<MenuItem>        items;
};

#ifdef BOOST_SPIRIT_X3_DEBUG
    [[maybe_unused]] std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Option)       { return os << "Option";       }
    [[maybe_unused]] std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Divider)      { return os << "Divider";      }
    [[maybe_unused]] std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, LockedOption) { return os << "LockedOption"; }
    [[maybe_unused]] std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Menu)         { return os << "Menu";         }
#endif

struct MenuItemFormatter : fmt::formatter<std::string> {
    template <typename... Ts>
    auto format(boost::variant<Ts...> const& var, auto& ctx) const {
        return boost::apply_visitor(
            [&](auto const& el) {
                return format_to(ctx.out(), fmt::runtime("{}"), el);
            }, var);
    }

    auto format(LockedOption const& lo, auto& ctx) const {
        auto out = fmt::format_to(ctx.out(), "LockedOption\n{{\n");
        for (auto const& [k, v] : lo.properties)
            out = fmt::format_to(out, "    {} \"{}\"\n", k, v);

        return fmt::format_to(out, "}}");
    }

    auto format(Divider const&, auto& ctx) const {
        return fmt::format_to(ctx.out(), "Divider");
    }

    auto format(Option const& o, auto& ctx) const {
        return fmt::format_to(ctx.out(), "Option \"{}\" \"{}\"", o.name, o.command);
    }

    auto format(Menu const& m, auto& ctx) const {
        return fmt::format_to(
            ctx.out(), "Menu \"{}\"\n{{\n    Title \"{}\"\n    {}\n}}", m.id,
            m.title.value_or(""), fmt::join(m.items, "\n    "));
    }
};

template <> struct fmt::formatter<MenuItem>     : MenuItemFormatter{};
template <> struct fmt::formatter<LockedOption> : MenuItemFormatter{};
template <> struct fmt::formatter<Divider>      : MenuItemFormatter{};
template <> struct fmt::formatter<Option>       : MenuItemFormatter{};
template <> struct fmt::formatter<Menu>         : MenuItemFormatter{};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Option, name, command)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(LockedOption, properties)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(LockedOption::Property, key, value)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Menu, id, title, items)

    namespace Parser {
        using namespace boost::spirit::x3;
        rule<struct menu_rule, Menu> const menu{"menu"};

        auto const qstring = rule<void, std::string>{"quoted string"} = //
            lexeme['"' > *('"' >> char_('"') | ~char_('"')) > '"'];

        auto const option = rule<void, Option>{"option"} = //
            "Option" > qstring > qstring;

        auto property   = lexeme[+graph] > qstring;
        auto properties = rule<void, LockedOption::Properties>{"properties"} =
            *((!lit('}')) > property > eol);

        auto const lockedoption = rule<void, LockedOption>{"lockedoption"} = //
            "LockedOption" > eol                                             //
            > '{' > eol                                                      //
            > properties                                                     //
            > '}';

        auto divider = rule<void, Divider>{"divider"} = //
            lit("Divider") >> attr(Divider{});

        auto item = rule<void, MenuItem>{"menu|option|lockedoption|divider"} =
            menu | option | lockedoption | divider;

        auto title = "Title" > qstring;

        auto menu_def =                   //
            "Menu" > qstring > eol        //
            > '{' > eol                   //
            > -(title > eol)              //
            > *((!lit('}')) > item > eol) //
            > '}';

        auto ignore = blank | "//" >> *~char_("\r\n") >> (eol|eoi);

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(menu)

        Menu parseMenu(std::string const& text) try {
            Menu result;
            parse(begin(text), end(text), skip(ignore)[expect[menu] > *eol > eoi],
                  result);
            return result;
        } catch (expectation_failure<std::string::const_iterator> const& ef) {
            throw std::runtime_error(
                "At " + std::to_string(std::distance(begin(text), ef.where())) +
                ": Expected " + ef.which() + " (Got '" +
                std::string(ef.where(), std::find(ef.where(), end(text), '\n')) +
                "')");
        }
    } // namespace Parser

int main() {
    for (std::string const& sample :
         {
             R"(    Menu "MenuName"
                        {
                            Menu "SubMenuName"
                            {
                                Option "OptionName" "Command"
                                Option "OptionName" "Command"
                            }
                        }
                    // This is a comment line
                    // // [ curly brackets in comment lines are made square so they don't get counted as balancing)",
             R"(    Menu "MenuName"{
                            Menu "SubMenuName"
                            {
                                Option "OptionName" "Command"
                                Option "OptionName" "Command"   }
                        }Menu "That bracket would be wrong since the line should end afterwards.
                        {   //this would also be wrong
                    // Nothing should ever follow a bracket except a End Of Line character.)",
             R"(//DO NOT DELETE, needs a line here for some reason.
                    Menu "MenuNameTEMPLATE"
                    {
                        Title "TitleName"
                        Option "OptionName" "Command"
                        Divider
                        LockedOption
                        {
                            DisplayName "OptionName"
                            Command "Command"
                            Icon "IconName"
                            PowerReady "PowerIdentifiers"
                        }
                        LockedOption
                        {
                            DisplayName "OptionName"
                            Command "Command"
                            Icon "IconName"
                            Badge "BadgeIdentifiers"
                        }
                        LockedOption
                        {
                            DisplayName "OptionName"
                            Command "Command"
                            Icon "IconName"
                        }
                        Menu "SubMenuName"
                        {
                            Title "TitleName"
                            Option "OptionName" "Command"
                            Option "OptionName" "Command"
                        }
             })",
             R"(Menu "Not So Good"
                {
                    Title "Uhoh"
                    Road Rage
                }
             )",
         }) //
    {
        static int i = 0;
        fmt::print("----- {}\n", ++i);
        try {
            fmt::print("Parsed: {}\n", Parser::parseMenu(sample));
        } catch (std::exception const& e) {
            std::cout << "Parse failed: " << e.what() << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess OP tags with `boost` because Notepad++ uses Boost regex flavour.

Comment: @Toto That'd be correct , I tagged it `boost` because Notepad++ uses the Boost regular expression library and Stackoverflow prompted tagging the regex flavor. I've never worked with C++ or really any serious programming language before.

Comment: Except that what library is used doesn't define the syntax. See: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax.html - Perl is the default. And I can guarantee it's not one of the arcane POSIX flavours :)